# vector space addition

Tags: vector-spaces

Could someone throw some light on the following notation. Say $A, B$ are vector spaces.

Then $C=A\oplus B$.

What does this sign (plus inside a circle) mean for vector spaces?

Appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean $\oplus$ which means the *direct sum* of vector spaces. Basically it means that any vector $c$ in $C$ can be written in exactly one way as a sum $c=a+b$ where $a$ is in $A$ and $b$ is in $B$. The canonical example is $C=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $A$ and $B$ are the $x$ and $y$ axes respectively.

Comment: you mean in $c$ can be written in unique way

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4):

The subspace $C$ is a direct sum of the subspaces $A$ and $B$ and we write
$$C=A\oplus B$$
if one of these equivalent statements holds:

- $C=A+B$ and $A\cap B=\{0\}$
- For all $c\in C$ there exist a unique $a\in A$ and unique $b\in B$ such that $c=a+b$

Answer (score 1):

It's the direct sum. $C = \{a+b, a\in A,b\in B\}$, and you're assuming that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint spaces, except for the zero vector.

Comment: Disjoint except for the zero vector.

Comment: That's true, thanks.